# How do I insert newline characters in single XML tag?

Tags: java, xml

I'm generating XML using Java, but the header tag is coming in a single line.

I would like to break it into multiple lines.

Current:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><cs:UnitPriceData xmlns:cs="URI:www.computershare.com.au:2004:XMLSchemaBase/UnitPrice" xmlns:err="URI:www.computershare.com.au:2004:XMLSchemaBase/PSError&#10;" xmlns:ns1="URI:www.computershare.com.au:2004:XMLSchemaBase/PSErrorRequest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Expected Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>                                                                              
<cs:UnitPriceData                                                                                   
xmlns:err="URI:www.computershare.com.au:2004:XMLSchemaBase/PSError"                                 
xmlns:ns1="URI:www.computershare.com.au:2004:XMLSchemaBase/PSErrorRequest"                          
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                               
xmlns:cs="URI:www.computershare.com.au:2004:XMLSchemaBase/UnitPrice">
```

Comment: Even notepad can do that... If your question about some text editor - superuser.com would be more appropriate place. If you have coding question - XML can't write itself and you probably should show code/tag with language you are using/looking for help with.

Comment: Thanks Alexei. But my requirement is to generate it through the java code only .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Do you have some code that you can share?

Comment: Are you using a parser library or did you code it yourself? If you're using a library, try to google `<library name> pretty format` or something like that. More information would be greatly appreciated (see [ask]?).